# Uk Tax year and limited companies

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, private-company

I want to open a uk private limited company but wondered if there are any advantages to wait a month so it will be registered in the new tax year.

I know the financials have to be submitted 12 after registration so there should be no benefit here but is there something i could be missing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For tax purposes, will the company be operating at all in the current tax year? e.g. any income or expenses?

Comment: There will be expenses